# Why is my FormData empty when submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, ionic-framework

My formData consumes the inputs of a reactive form: `categoryForm`. I have to do that in order to upload my data.But when I submit my formData and console.log it, I get just: `FormData {}` so an empty form. But I don't know why since im getting the value of each data with `this.categoryForm.get('name').value`
My reactive form is actually receiving the data and the form has all the data, so the problem is that formData does not get the data.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="categoryForm">
                    <ion-item mode="ios" lines="none" class="checkbox-tag rounded-tag">
                        <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
                      <ion-checkbox formControlName="lock"></ion-checkbox>              

<div> 
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [disabled]="tagList?.length > 0" mode="md" formControlName="category" clearInput="true" placeholder="Tag" name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="addTag()" [disabled]="!categoryForm.valid || tagList?.length > 0"  item-right icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
</div>

</form>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer">

        <ion-button 
        [disabled]="!tagList?.length > 0" 
        (click)="apiSubmit()"
        expand="block" 
        color="secondary" 
        fill="solid"
        >POST</ion-button>
  </ion-footer>
```

ts:

```
     ngOnInit() {

  this.storage.get('image_data').then((imageFile) => {
      console.log(imageFile)
      this.categoryForm.patchValue({
        'image': this.storage.get('image_data')
      });

      this.storage.get('when').then((whenData) => {
        this.categoryForm.patchValue({
          'when': this.storage.get('when')
        });
      });
    });

        this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({

          'lock': new FormControl(true),


          'category': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
            Validators.maxLength(25),
            Validators.minLength(1),
            Validators.required
          ])),

          'image': new FormControl(null),
          'when': new FormControl(null),
        });

    }

    apiSubmit() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('lock', this.categoryForm.get('lock').value);
      formData.append('category', this.categoryForm.get('category').value);
      formData.append('image', this.categoryForm.get('image').value);
      formData.append('when', this.categoryForm.get('when').value);
      console.log(formData);

      this.http.post<any>(`{this.url}`, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
    }
```

Comment: When are you going to start including enough information in your posts so someone here can help you? You've posted this same bit of code in various forms over the past few days, not once have you given a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why anyone up-voted this is beyond me.

Comment: @R. Richards Ok sorry, you are right Im struggling for some days with the same issue and I tried many things, but nothin worked. Sorry when my questions were bad, I thought to much code would be deterrent. I added my template and the additional relevant typescript.

Answer (score 0):

why not use categoryForm itself to get the value, like this:

```
const value = this.categoryForm.value
```

Comment: so I should just append my whole form info in one `formData.append()` like that: `formData.append('allData', this.categoryForm.value);`?

Comment: does your post request need data of type formData?

Comment: I have strings, files, numbers and bools. The problem is that I tried it with the normal form but I had problems with uploading the file. So I want to try formData if that work better...

Comment: with this `formData.append('allData', this.categoryForm.value);`approach the form is still empty

Comment: do you want to get the value inside the form or are you trying to populate the form?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by populate... but with categoryForm I get the data from my template and then I want to patch the data of categoryForm in my formData form.

Comment: okay so after getting the value from categoryForm, you want to use that data to fill another form named 'formData'?. Anyway, categoryForm.value will give a js object and you can convert it to json if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes.I actually want just that the data from categoryForm is displayed the same way in formData, so yes this might be a js Object. I just need my file to be there correctly in order that my upload works

Comment: what do you see when you log just `this.categoryForm.value` inside apiSubmit ..is it empty? If it is empty update the question with the template.

Comment: It logs my whole form with all the data in it. The problem is 100% not with the template because I get back all the data